# Android: How to do fast scrolling for ScrollView with one TextView like in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, textview, scrollview, fastscroll

I have to show a log file in a TextView which is within a ScrollView. When the log file is bigger, it is very hard to scroll to the end of the view.

So how can I implement a fast scrolling like in ListView with 'fastScrollEnabled'? ScrollView and TextView does not support fast scroll.

I searched here, but I didn´t find any answer to this question. One hint was to do it yourself, but how?

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Calling this on your `ScrollView` will scroll the view to the bottom.
If you wish to enable/disable animated scroll transitions, toggle the `ScrollView`'s smooth scrolling property.

```
scrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Good hint, but I want to scroll myself fast thru the text